# How to I generate a CSV file from a python list with each list item in a seperate row

Tags: python, csv

I've tried some code I got from another question (list_of_paths is a list I generated earlier in the code)

```
myfile = open('/home/graham/Desktop/Experiment/listcsv.csv', 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
wr.writerow(list_of_paths)
```

But it put the entire list in one cell. I want each item in a different row. The program I use for CSV files is LibreOffice Calc if that makes a difference.

Comment: What is the contents of `list_of_paths`? list-of-strings / list-of-list?

Comment: maybe `writerows()` instead of `writerow()`

Comment: @cmd if `list_of_paths` is indeed a list (or other iterable) then I think you're right :)

Comment: list_of_paths is a list of 77 file paths (ex. /home/graham/Desktop/Experiment/Experiment_images/1/which_image.csv)
I just tried writerows() and it worked except every character in the file path is within quotations. (ex. /,"h","o","m","e","/","g","r","a","h","a","m","/","D","e","s","k","t","o","p","/","E","x","p","e","r","i","m","e","n","t","/","E","x","p","e","r","i","m","e","n","t","_","i","m","a","g","e","s","/","1","/","w","h","i","c","h","_","i","m","a","g","e",".","c","s","v")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `writerows` as follow:

```
myfile = open('/home/graham/Desktop/Experiment/listcsv.csv', 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
wr.writerows([path] for path in list_of_paths)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use standard Input/Output to implement this.

```
$ cat getCSV.py 
input_list = range(10)   # replace range(10) with your list
for elem in input_list:
    print '"' + str(elem) + '"'

$ python getCSV.py > output.csv
$ cat output.csv 
"0"
"1"
"2"
"3"
"4"
"5"
"6"
"7"
"8"
"9"
```

And if each elem in your list is again, a list or tuple.. you could use join command to separate them into columns.

```
>>> row = [str(i) for i in range(10)]
>>> row
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
>>> ','.join(row)
'0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9'
>>> ','.join(['"' + col + '"' for col in row])
'"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"'
```